# include jquery in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails application  I am trying to include  jquery focus effect for a search button. When the mouse is over that button it should change the color. But the jquery code is not working ,although I tried using search.js,search.js.erb.In the gems file  I have also included jquery rails in Gem file and also tried bundle install.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("text_field_tag").focus(function(){
      $(this).css("background-color","#cccccc");
      });
      $("text_field_tag").blur(function(){
      $(this).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
      });
      });
    </script>
    <body>
      <%=form_tag({controller: 'tweets', action:'index'},  method: "get") do %>
      <%=label_tag(:search, "Search for:") %>
      <%=text_field_tag(:text) %>
      <%=label_tag(:show, "Show for:") %>
      <%=text_field_tag(:show) %>
      <%= submit_tag( "GO" ) %>
      <% end %>
    </body>

</html>
```

I also tried by removing the   "script src" tag even then its not working.Anybody please help..

Answer (score 0):

you did a small mistake, but don't worry. Do as I suggest below. 
1) Give the id for the text_field_tag like <%=text_field_tag(:show,'',:id=>'show_fld') %> 
2) Take that id and keep that as a DOM in jQuery  function. Like

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show_fld").focus(function(){
      $(this).css("background-color","#cccccc");
    });
    $("#show_fld").blur(function(){
      $(this).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Now the above will work.

Comment: how should my file be named   should it be named as  search.js.erb?

Comment: `$('#element_id')` is how you select elements in jQuery. Your jquery code is wrong, not the filename

Comment: tried that also its not working ..I am getting the error "Missing template tweets/search, application/search with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/niranjan/tweetsblog7/app/views" . Should I modify som other file or include someother file?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rails 3, you can use sprockets to include everything you need.

- Add `gem 'query-rails'` to the assets group of your Gemfile
- add both `//= require jquery` and `//= require jquery_ujs` to your application.js file
- Make sure your application.html.erb file still includes `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`